# OS X Leopard Safari shows questionmark?

Tags: safari, imac, leopard

The Safari icon indicates a question mark. And, it wont let me go to internet etc. How do I find the Safari app and activate it?

Comment: I suppose the question mark shows in the dock. You can remove it from there. You should find the Safari app in Applications folder.

Answer (score 1):

Pratika Rana is correct: your icon for Safari in the dock is no longer working. Remove it from the dock by dragging it out or by control-clocking and selecting 'remove from dock'

- find Safari by opening finder and choosing Go -> Applications f of the menu. Double-click to open.
- Safari, once it starts, will now have a new icon in your dock. Control-click its icon and select 'keep in dock' to make sure it doesn't disappear as you as you quit Safari.